# Public Key encryption with .NET and decryption with Java

Tags: c#, java, web-services, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have a requirement where a Java Web service exposes methods for clients to obtain a PublickKey (as a PEM String) and submit data to the web service encrypted by the PublicKey. The client of the service is .NET app. On the Java side a keystore is created with a keypair (RSA 1024 bits) as shown below
keytool.exe -genkey -alias abc -keystore sample.ks -storetype jceks -storepass xyz

The .NET client obtains the PublicKey via the webservice and then use that public Key to encrypt some sensitive data to call the web service with the encrypted data. The web service decrypts the data using the private key avavailable from keystore and stores the contents in the DB. I cannot use any WS-Security capabilities for client compatibility reasons.

The webservice reads the keystore and returns the Public Key as a PEM string.
The .NET Client gets the PublicKey as a PEM string and creates a RSACryptoServiceProvider using this and it works without any issues. It then ecrypts the data and submits it back to the Java webservice.

**The Java Service decrypts the data but the problem I have is that it prints out garbage (not ASCII data).I don't get any exceptions.**

I have attached the snippets (simplified) of code here

.NET Client Side

```
  var registrationService = new RegistrationService();
  var pKey = registrationService.getPublickey();
  //pKey is a PEM String
  X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pKey));

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

    var encryptedMsg = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Secret Data"), false);
    var encoded_msg = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMsg);

    registrationService.submitRegistration(encoded_msg);
```

Java Side:

```
   public void submitRegistration(String inputData)
   {
   //Decoding the encoded and encrypted message in the webservice      
   PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromKeyStore("abc");
   //I know I am using JDK proprietary classes, but I can easily replace this
   byte[] dataInBytes = new Base64Decoder().deodeBuffer(inputData)

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding"); 
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
   byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataInBytes);          
   String original = new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");
   System.out.println("Original Data : " + original);
}
  public String getPublicKey()
  {
    Certificate cert = getKeyStore().getCertificate("abc");
    byte[] encodedCert = cert.getEncoded();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    sw.write("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
    sw.write(new Base64Encoder().encode(encodedCert));
    sw.write("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
    return sw.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Have you searched this site yet?  I have seen very similar questions many times.

Comment: Yes, I have searched the site. I do see similar questions could not find an answer that addressed the issue I am facing. Also the subtle variation I have is that I have to get the PublicKey via a web service as against reading from a file. Wondering if someone else had a similar issue and would throw me a pointer.

Comment: You are using PKCS#1 padding on the .NET side but not on the Java side. Change the NoPadding to PKCS1PADDING

Comment: I tried it but got an exception as shown below. (I am using BouncyCastle Provider - bcprov-jdk14-125.jar for deployment reasons). Do you think this it could be fixed with bcprov-jdk15?  ----javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: unknown block type
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(JCERSACipher
.java:292)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA12275)

Comment: And that exception means that your public and private keys are not related, or the data is corrupted.

Comment: Also, I don't see where you Base64-decode the public key in your .NET code.

Comment: Thanks GregS for taking the time to look at this. In the .NET code, I did not need to do a Base64-decode code. The doc for X509Certificate2 says it can take DER or Base64 encoded data(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413.aspx). So I used it without any conversion. The interesting thing is that I have exactly the same programs in C# and in Java (except it is console app as against a web service). I encrypt the data in C# and write it a file. read it back from Java which loads the private key and unencrypts it perfectly fine. The problem happens when I convert this to a Webservice.

Comment: Kris, never directly encrypt with RSA, and always use a padding scheme. It might be that the size of input data makes the difference, but you really should use a random "session" AES key and PKCS#1 padding to make your scheme less brittle.

Comment: Thanks GregS.  Turns out my coworker generated a new keystore and put in the DB with the same name (we place the keystore in the DB) without informing. Usually we have individual keystores, but he did not change the property file I had given him. Wasted three days of effort because of it. Anyway I am using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding for specifying the ciper as suggested by GregS for .NET clients and it has worked.

Comment: @GregS could you post "wrong key" and PKCS1Padding as an answer so Kris can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to notice is that you're using "NOPADDING" on the Java side but .NET is using PKCS1Padding.

Since PKCS1 padding pads plaintext with 0x00 0x02 at the high order end this also provides a way for the decrypting side to check that it is using a correct private key. However, note that the chance of a wrong key decrypting to plaintext that starts with 0x00 0x02 is at least 1/65536, so this check cannot be relied on entirely to detect an incorrect private key. In your case, you used an incorrect key and the plaintext failed this check, so you received the exception. Now, when you specify NOPADDING you are saying that all plaintext are valid, and any further checking will be done by your application.

Comment: +1 interesting that 1/64Ki issue when the decrypt suddenly works :), just shows everyone that creating a secure integrity check (a signature would be good) over the cipher text always makes sense.